# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token .. Doc type is not valid json error

Tags: unity, webgl

I've a Unity WebGL game.

When I try to load my game hosted on an Ubuntu 20.04 + apache 2.4 server, I get this error:

> Uncaught Syntax Error:  Unexpected token .. Doc type is not valid json.

I've already this code in my web.config:

```
   <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
           <staticContent>
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".unityweb" mimeType ="TYPE/SUBTYPE" />
           </staticContent>
        </system.webServer>
     </configuration>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your root issue, but the correct mime type is `application/octet-stream`, not `TYPE/SUBTYPE`